# WebView element error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.oLangWebViewInterface.callJSFunction'

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm having trouble to work with web-view since I have upgraded my native-script version in my system to **native script 6.0.1**.

The below error that I get :

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.oLangWebViewInterface.callJSFunction

```
import :
import { WebView, LoadEventData } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/web-view/';
create :
let webViewInterfaceModule = require('nativescript-webview-interface');

child:
 @ViewChild('installationWebView', {static: false}) webView: ElementRef;

object:
    private oLangWebViewInterface;


   ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.setupWebViewInterface();
    }

function
 private setupWebViewInterface() {
        let webView: WebView = this.webView.nativeElement;

        this.oLangWebViewInterface = new webViewInterfaceModule.WebViewInterface(webView, '~/www/index.html');

        if (webView.android) { // in IOS android will be undefined
            webView.android.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        }

        // loading devices in dropdown, on load of webView.
        webView.on(WebView.loadFinishedEvent, (args: LoadEventData) => {
            let message: string;
            if (!args.error) {
                message = `WebView finished loading of ${args.url}`;

            } else {
                message = `Error loading ${args.url} : ${args.error}`;
            }
            console.log(`WebView message - ${message}`);
        });

        this.listenLangWebViewEvents();
    }
```

connect to device function :

```
private connectToDevice() {
        //this.isConnecting = true;
        this.oLangWebViewInterface.callJSFunction('connectToDevice', null, (response: any) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

        });
    }
```

Comment: html :  <web-view style="visibility: collapsed;overflow:hidden;" height="1px" width="1px" #installationWebView>
                    </web-view>

Comment: When you do call `connectToDevice()`?

Comment: after user tap on button text="connect"

Comment: user should connect the phone to the iot device and then click on connect

Comment: May I know why you have set `visibility: collapsed`? Did you try whether removing that makes any difference.

Comment: yeah didnt help \=

Comment: Please share the sample project where the issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

i try to change the code to this

public onWebViewLoaded(webargs: any) {

const webview: WebView = webargs.object;

console.log("onWebViewLoaded() " + webview);

this.oLangWebViewInterface = new WebViewInterface(webview, '~/www/index.html');
// if (webView.android) {

// in IOS android will be undefined

// webView.android.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);

// }

webview.on(WebView.loadFinishedEvent, (args: LoadEventData) => {
let message = "";

if (!args.error) {

message = WebView finished loading of ${args.url};
} else {

message = Error loading ${args.url} : ${args.error};
}

console.log(WebView message - ${message});

});

this.listenLangWebViewEvents();
}

import { WebViewInterface } from 'nativescript-webview-interface';

import { WebView, LoadEventData } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/web-view';

and know I only have a problem with the

WebView message - Error loading ~'/www/index.html': The requested URL was not found on this server.